# Is it possible to compile a ColdFusion (Lucee) Project, so that no one can read the source code?

Tags: web, coldfusion, lucee

See the question in the headline.

If not - do you know any other Web-Language or Framework, where I can encode or compile the source code?

Thank you very much.

Best regards

berti

Comment: This might help.  http://niallodoherty.com/assets/content/enclosures/Documents/Sourceless%20Deployment%20of%20ColdFusion.pdf

Comment: That link is for ACF, but deploying as a WAR file applies to Lucee as well. See the [Application Distribution and Source Code Security section](http://www.lucee.nl/post.cfm/great-article-explaining-coldfusion-and-opensource-railo-versus-php). Not sure if Lucee offers other methods. Keep in mind compiling to byte code obviously does not mean it cannot be read. ie It could still be decompiled by someone motivated enough to get at it.

Comment: The coldfusion product now owned by Adobe used to ship with a tool that was used to encrypt all cfml files while still allowing them to run on the server. And yes there was a tool floating around that let you decrypt. 

Even java you can decompile to get back at the source.